# Start server in background, run code and stop server again in single script

Tags: bash

I want to create a bash script that starts a server, waits for the server to be started, then runs some code (which us handled by the server) and finally stops the server again.

Here's what I've got, with remarks on why it's not working:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Expected: Start the local selenium server and push it to the background.
# Actual: Script continues instantly without waiting for the server to start!
selenium-server -port 4444 &

# Expected: Run the tests, which require the local selenium server to be started
# Actual: Tests fail because the server is not ready.
phpunit tests/ui-tests.php

# Expected: Exiting the process also stops the background job (server).
# Actual: The server continues running interactively in the terminal until stopped via Ctrl-C.
exit
```

What's the correct (or better) approach for this kind of script?

Comment: there is no concept of 'push into the background and wait for said process to start up' if simply because the OS has no idea what 'start up' means (eg, a simple web server may start and be ready for processing within 2 seconds while a largish database server could take hours to start up (worst case scenario); before you run your `phpunit` command **you** will need to add a step to either a) `sleep` for XX seconds (pick a number you're sure will guarantee the server has started) or b) write a small loop/poll process to periodically sleep-then-check for server availability (ie, is it 'up')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the working script which I built based on the feedback of markp-fuso:

```
#!/bin/bash

start_server() {
    echo "Start server ..."
    selenium-server -port 4444 &
    server_pid=$!

    # Wait for the server to start (max 10 seconds)
    for attempt in {1..10}; do
        my_pid=$(lsof -t -i tcp:4444)

        if [[ -n $my_pid ]]; then
            # Make sure the running server is the one we just started.
            if [[ $my_pid -ne $server_pid ]]; then
                echo "ERROR: Multiple Selenium Servers running."
                echo "→ lsof -t -i tcp:4444 | xargs kill"
                exit 1
            fi

            break
        fi

        sleep 1
    done

    if [[ -z $my_pid ]]; then
        echo "ERROR: Timeout while waiting for Selenium Server"
        exit 1
    fi
}

stop_server() {
    echo "Stop Server ..."
    kill $server_pid
}

# - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 

start_server

phpunit tests/ui-tests.php

stop_server
```

Comment: **NOTE**: I'm not familiar with `selenium-server` so fwiw ... is the `lsof/tcp:4444` test sufficient to verify the server is up? might it make more sense to run a small/sample 'query' (eg, `phpunit <test_query>`) to verify that not only is it listening on port (tcp)4444 but is also a) accepting connections and b) returning the expected value from the `<test_query>` ... ?  [eg, I work with (Sybase) database servers and the existence of a listener running against a port isn't enough to guarantee that the server is up 100% let alone that I can connect to my desired database and run a query]

Comment: That's a very good point! In my current tests, the port-check is sufficient, since the server takes ~1 sec to start. From what I understand, selenium is a very lightweight HTTP server that should always start quickly (it's a test environment that only receives "local traffic"). Maybe I'll add an extra `sleep 1` at the end of `start_server` ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have a function called dev that starts my server in the background, then waits, that way I can use a `trap dev_term INT` to clean up everything with `ctrl-c`. Usually I have a frontend server and a backend server running in the background so I'm excited to apply this to that.

```
function dev_term() {
    kb
    docker compose -f dev-compose.yml down
}

function dev () {
    local start=$(pwd)
    gotoroot
    trap dev_term INT
    docker compose -f dev-compose.yml up -d
    cd backend && python manage.py runserver &
    backend_pid=$!
    wait
}

function kb () {
    kill $backend_pid 2>/dev/null
}
```